# Show that $24 \mid (n - 1)n(n + 1)(n + 2)$ for all positive integers $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> Show that $24 \mid (n - 1)n(n + 1)(n + 2)$ for all positive integers $n$.

Since $24 = 2^3 \cdot 3$ it follows that $(n - 1)n(n + 1)(n + 2)$ is divisible by $3$ since it contains the product of three consecutive numbers.

If $n$ is odd then $n-1$ and $n+1$ are even and other one of them is divisible by $2$ and the other by $4$, thus the product is divisible by $2^3$.

If $n$ is even then $n$ and $n+2$ are both even and similar reasoning follows that other one is divisible by $2$ and the other by $4$.

Is this correct? For the odd case if I have that $n=1$ then $n-1=0$ and $n+1=2$, but neither one is divisible by $4$ here? Or does $0$ count as being divisible by $4$?

Comment: $0$ is divisible by $4$, and your proof works.

Comment: So in other words, you want an elementary proof that $\binom{n+2}{4}$ is an integer for all integers $n$?

Comment: What Daniel said. For any $k$ we have that the "descending factorial" $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)$ is divisible by $k!$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes, that a standard method. See the linked dupes for this and other well-known methods.

Answer (score 1):

You have four consecutive terms, so exactly one of them is divisible by $4$, another is divisible by $2$, and at least one other is divisible by $3$.

QED.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Other approach, by induction.

For $ n=1 $, it is true.

Let $ n\ge 1 $ such that
$$24|\color{red}{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}.$$

Replacing $ n $, by $ n+1$,

$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=\color{red}{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}+4n(n+1)(n+2)$$

So, you just need to prove that
$$6|n(n+1)(n+2)$$